# Want to use GenericRepository with Base Entity class, detail below

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I am using C# winform with EntityFramework version 6. I have a generic interface like this

```
public interface IGenericInterface<T> where T:class
    {
        RepoResult<T> Insert(T obj);
        RepoResult<T> Update(T obj);
        RepoResult<T> Delete(long id);
        RepoResult<T> Restore(long id);
        T GetSingle(long id);
    }
```

Ignore return type **RepoResult**

I want to create a generic repository with base entity class

I am using this models (base class)

```
public class _Base
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DeletedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? RestoredAt { get;set; }
    }
```

I am using this model class (std)

```
public class std:_Base
    {
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(25)]
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to create a generic repository that can access these model classes as **T** but I want to update **CreatedAt** / **UpdatedAt** / **DeletedAt** / **RestoredAt** from Generic repository.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access them, you just need to add a constraint to the generic interface that is a more specific T like this:

```
public interface IGenericInterface<T> where T: _Base
    {
        RepoResult<T> Insert(T obj);
        RepoResult<T> Update(T obj);
        RepoResult<T> Delete(long id);
        RepoResult<T> Restore(long id);
        T GetSingle(long id);
    }
```

Since _Base is already a class itself, you don't need to worry about that extra class constraint.

Comment: Hello Sir, can not understand this. If I add **_Base** as an inherited class then how I can access **DeletedAt** on **std** model class? Please help

Comment: got that. thank you so much sir for your help.

Comment: No problem!  It takes a bit to get used to both Generics and their constraints, but they are very powerful once you do!